# How do I fix this Unhandled Error Event in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user signup form in my web app and after I upgraded to Mongo 3.6 and Mongoose v5.9.10 I started getting this node server error for my user signup function.

I'm using Node v8.17.0

1) Where is the location of 'events.js'? (I'm not seeing it referenced in the error stack)

2) Is this a problem with something else that I'm not aware of?

I've already tried changing port numbers, rebooting server, deleting node_modules folder and npm install. Nothing is working.

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
TypeError: respond is not a function
    at /home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/mongoose-unique-validator/index.js:43:9
    at /home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4850:16
    at /home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4850:16
    at /home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    at /home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4873:21
    at _hooks.execPost (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4379:11)
    at /home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/kareem/index.js:135:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

Here is the function that runs right before this error is thrown:

```
UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

/**
 * Hook a pre save method to hash the password
 */
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    console.log("save");
    if (this.password && this.password.length > 0) {
        console.log("hashing password");
        this.salt = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'), 'base64');
        this.password = this.hashPassword(this.password);
    }

    next();
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code as well? Please share all the relevant details in question always.

Comment: Just added the function that runs prior to the error being thrown.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's an issue with how I have my `UserSchema.pre()` function organized, and compatabilit with Mongoose v5.9.10.

Comment: What version of `mongoose-unique-validator` are you using? You might want to update it to latest version `2.0.3` and check if that works.

Comment: https://github.com/blakehaswell/mongoose-unique-validator/issues/82

Comment: Thank you @ambianBeing. That fixed it!

Comment: @tonejac welcome . Do consider posting that as an answer and accept so that future readers of the question might find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `mongoose-unique-validator` module was out of date, and causing the error with the latest versions of MongoDB and Mongoose. Thank you to @ambianBeing for the tip.

I did:
`npm install --save mongoose-unique-validator@latest` to make the problem go away.